# How does functions as a service ( FaaS) hosting work under the hood?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, virtual-machine, azure-functions, serverless-framework

## hypothesis

Suppose I want to roll out my own FaaS hosting, a service **like Lambda, not on Lambda**.

## analogy

I have an abstract understanding of other cloud services as follows
1. **Infrastructure as a service (IaaS)**: Create virtual machines for tenants on your hardware.
2. **Platform as a service (PaaS)**: Create VM and run script that loads the required environment.
The above could also be achieved with docker images.

## What about FaaS?

AWS uses firecracker VM for Lambda functions. But what's not clear is how the VMs are triggered on and off, how they're orchestrated on multiple pieces of hardware in a multi-tenant environment. Could someone explain how the complete life cycle works?

Comment: The exact workings are a) propriety and b) constantly chaning anyways. There are plenty of well documented open source implementations of FAAS though, mainly built on Kubernetes and/or Docker. Just do a web search for OpenWhisk, Fission, IronFunctions, OpenFAAS or one of the other umpteen implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The main features of AWS Lambda and Cloud Function can be found in 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/compute#faas_comparison

I can include the information of what I know, that is Google Cloud Functions.

**Triggers**

Cloud Functions can be triggered in two ways: HTTP request or Event-triggered. [Events and Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers). The events are things that happen into your project: A file is updated in Cloud Storage or Cloud Firestore. Other events are: a Compute Engine instance (VM) is initialized or the source code is updated in your repository.

All these events can be the trigger of a Cloud Function. This function, when triggered, is executed in a VM that will receive a HTTP request, and context information to perform its duty.

**Auto-scaling and machine-type**

If the volume that arrives to a Cloud Function increases, it [auto-scales](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#auto-scaling_and_concurrency). That is that instead of having one VM executing one request at a time. You will have more than one VMs that server one request at a time. In any instance, only one request at a time will be analyzed.

If you want more information, you can check it on the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec).